# Setup Guest Network

Tags: networking, ethernet, access-point

I have a Pi 3B running the latest Raspbian setup as a routed wireless AP. The Pi and the devices connected to it are under subnet `192.168.47.1/24`. The Pi is connected to another router for WAN access. I intend to setup a guest network either as,

`1` Wireless AP guest network

`2` An ethernet guest network

Where the devices connected to the guest network have access to WAN but are isolated from `192.168.47.1/24`

I'm not sure which kind of guest network setup is supported by the Pi. I need help to setup either `1` or `2`.

Comment: Welcome! I'm having a hard time understanding the question: is your Pi's IP `192.168.47.1/24`? Have you configured your Raspberry Pi as a guest network, or do you intend to do so? Could you clarify this in your post? :)

Answer (score 3):

The built-in WiFi device on a Raspberry Pi is limited to create only one access point. To have a second access point for a guest network you need an additional USB/WiFi dongle. All other access issues are then only routing settings.

To have a wired connection to the additional guest network you also need a second USB dongle with an ethernet RJ45 port of course. You cannot plug two cables into one port ;-)